# Como crear una dll para consultar base de datos?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, librería

estoy haciendo una dll y esta me debe regresar cierta informacion, se compila correctamente pero al implementarlo en mi proyecto no me permite pasarle el parametro aqui *Empleados(int numero)*, creo que esta mal mi codigo, pueden darle una revisada aqui se los dejo.

```
 public class Class1
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=xxxx; Database=xxx; User ID=xxx; PWD=xxx");

    public class infoEmpleado
    {
        public int numeroEmpl { get; set; }
        public string empleado { get; set; }
        public string namesupervisor { get; set; }
        public string dpto2 { get; set; }
        public int numSup { get; set; }
    }
    public infoEmpleado Empleados(int numero)
    {
        SqlDataReader readedata;
        conn.Open();
        string activo;
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP", conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoEmpleado", numero);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        readedata = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (readedata.Read())
        {

            activo = readedata.GetString(7);

            if (activo == "S")
            {
                infoEmpleado empl = new Class1.infoEmpleado();

                empl.numeroEmpl = readedata.GetInt32(0);
                empl.empleado = readedata.GetString(1);
                empl.namesupervisor = readedata.GetString(4);
                empl.dpto2 = readedata.GetString(10);
                empl.numSup = Convert.ToInt32(readedata.GetString(11));
                conn.Close();
                return empl;

            }
            else
            {
                conn.Close();
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            conn.Close();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

lo instancio asi: pero no se donde mandarle el parametro?

```
 trsinfo.Class1.infoEmpleado datos = new trsinfo.Class1.infoEmpleado();
        int numpleado = datos.numeroEmpl;
        string empl = datos.empleado;
        string nasuoervisor = datos.namesupervisor;
        string dpto = datos.dpto2;
        int nusuoer = datos.numSup;
```

Comment: Y como lo estas implementando en tu proyecto, te aseguraste de agregar correctamente la referencia. coloca el codigo de como lo implementas.

Comment: la referencia si esta agregada al proyecto.

Comment: Podrias agregar el codigo de como instancias `Class1`

Comment: listo, agregue como lo estoy instanciando

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es el parámetro que no podes pasar, o que es realmente lo que no estas pudiendo hacer

Comment: Empleados(int numero) esta funcion espera un dato entero, pero no se como enviarlo desde donde instancio trsinfo.Class1.infoEmpleado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero debes instanciar la clase, y después llamar al método `Empleados(int numero)`.

```
int numero = 1;
trsinfo.Class1 class1 = new trsinfo.Class1();
trsinfo.Class1.infoEmpleado datos = class1.Empleados(numero);
int numpleado = datos.numeroEmpl;
string empl = datos.empleado;
string nasuoervisor = datos.namesupervisor;
string dpto = datos.dpto2;
int nusuoer = datos.numSup;
```

> Reemplaza el valor de la variable número por uno valido.

Answer (score -1):

comencemos por saber a que parámetros te refieres?, al de tu método Empleado (que te sugiero lo renombres para que se mas descriptivo como TraerEmpleado) "numero" o a la de tu cadena de conexión? 
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=xxxx; Database=xxx; User ID=xxx; PWD=xxx");

Si es a esta última pues, no estás definiendo ningún atributo para inicializar la cadena de conexión.

Otra cosa la clase infoEmpleado la tienes dentro de la clase Class1 o lo dejaste ahí para fines ilustrativos?, pero igual, esa clase tiene datos de un empleado, luego tienes un método dentro de una clase diferente que otra vez trabaja con el empleado, y llena las propiedades que tiene la clase infoEmpleado, tanto las propiedades como el método que las lee deben de estar en la misma clase esto es separación de intereses, en programación orientada a objetos se logra con la encapsulación, las propiedades y métodos que interactúan con ellas deben estar en la misma entidad (digamos tu clase), acá algunos enlaces de interés
[POO](https://csharp.com.es/poo/)

[Principios de la arquitectura](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/architectural-principles)

Aunque le falta (por ejemplo la conexión con la base de datos no debe ser así), te dejo esta implementación:

```
public class Empleado
{
    public int numeroEmpl { get; set; }
    public string empleado { get; set; }
    public string namesupervisor { get; set; }
    public string dpto2 { get; set; }
    public int numSup { get; set; }

    SqlConnection conn;

    public Empleado(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        conn = connection;
    }

    public bool Leer(int numero)
    {
        SqlDataReader readedata;
        conn.Open();
        string activo;
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP", conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoEmpleado", numero);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        readedata = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (readedata.Read())
        {

            activo = readedata.GetString(7);

            if (activo == "S")
            {

                numeroEmpl = readedata.GetInt32(0);
                empleado = readedata.GetString(1);
                namesupervisor = readedata.GetString(4);
                dpto2 = readedata.GetString(10);
                numSup = Convert.ToInt32(readedata.GetString(11));
                conn.Close();

                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                conn.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            conn.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Y lo instanciamos así:

```
        var con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=xxxx; Database=xxx; User ID=xxx; PWD=xxx");
        var empleado = new Empleado(con);

        if (empleado.Leer(1))
        {
            //en este momento el empleado con número 1 ha sido leído y todas sus propiedades inicializadas, ya puedes acceder a esos datos
            Console.WriteLine($"El valor de namesupervisor es {empleado.namesupervisor}");
        }
```

Comment: pondre un poco de contexto, la idea de poner la conexion a la base de datos a como lo tengo dentro del dll, es porque esa dll la utilizara un proveedor que me da soporte, pero no quiero darle acceso al servidor de base de datos directamente, en tu respuesta estas haciendo la conexion desde que instancias la dll y no es lo que busco.

Comment: y no es a ese parametro al que me refiero, sino en base a tu ejemplo seria al Leer();

Comment: @Manny mi intención es ayudarte, de hecho en mi explicación se deja ver que el problema en realidad es la estructura que le estás dando a tu código, porque según tu último comentario instancias la clase infoEmpleado que solo tiene propiedades y luego quieres ejecutar el método Empleado que es parte de la clase Class1, ves el error de diseño?, antes de marcar una respuesta como no útil; a como hiciste con la mía asegúrate de entenderla bien, porque esas reacciones termianrán dañando tu reputación y luego no se te querrá ayudar, te agradecería que revirtieras tu voto en mi comentario

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, recuerda que esta zona es para respuestas sobre la pregunta, si deseas preguntar aclaraciones estas se realizan en los comentarios , revisar [answer],.saludos.